# Sending emails via node on a firebase project

Tags: node.js, firebase, dialogflow-es

I'm working on a google action that I've written in node and am deploying to firebase to interact via intents defined on API.AI.

I'd like to implement a feature that sends an email to a specific address when a specific intent is activated. I've tried using the nodemail and sendmail packages, but after deploying with them, they don't seem to send the email when the correct intent is invoked. I'm not sure if the problem is that I've coded it wrong (a distinct possibility given my inexperience) or if there's some inherent problem with specifying these packages on a firebase deploy. I've been able to verify that I'm getting inside the code that executes the `sendmail` by simply returning a response to API.AI from within it; if I'm able to access firebase or API.AI logs, I'm not sure how. API.AI shows a JSON response, but that's about it, as far as I can tell.

Here's some simplified code (only the relevant parts):

```
const sendmail = require('sendmail')();

const getSuggestion = app => {

    const rawInput = app.getRawInput();

    sendmail({
        from: 'no-reply@yourdomain.com',
        to: 'myemail@gmail.com',
        subject: 'test sendmail',
        html: rawInput,
        }, function(err, reply) {
        console.log(err && err.stack);
        console.dir(reply);
        return app.ask('You said ' + rawInput + '. Do you have any further input?');
    });

};
```

Comment: Are you seeing errors?  Do you have some minimal code that doesn't work the way you expect?  Are you using Cloud Functions for Firebase?

Comment: I'm not seeing any sort of errors in the API.AI interface or the JSON response. I threw some code up there in the answer. I've read that there's a way to use Cloud Functions to send emails, but I was hoping to skirt that and do something very simple.

Comment: I actually ended up getting this working using the Cloud Functions. I don't think it's possible to do using the regular node packages embedded in the firebase deploy, but obviously I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample using Cloud Functions for Firebase (aka Firebase Functions), nodemailer and Gmail: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/email-users

API.AI indicates a 206 in API.AI's simulator when the webhook call fails, because some content is usally sen by API.AI even if the webhook call fails. If you see a 206 after clicking "Show JSON" check your webhook (in this case Firebase) logs to debug.  Here are some screenshots:
[image]

Clicking "SHOW JSON" creates the following popup:

[image]

This `206 partial_content Webhook call failed. Error: Webhook response was empty.` indicates some sort of error with your webhook, either a 500 error, a successful response that couldn't was formatted incorrectly or you're incorrectly entered the HTTPS URL for your webhook.